# Sequência de Fibonacci em C

Tags: c

Tô fazendo um exercício da faculdade em que o usuário deve digitar um número e o programa deve retornar a sequência de Fibonacci. Porém, segundo o professor, ele deveria começar no 0 (ZERO), mas meu programa começa no 1.

Obs.: O professor já corrigiu e não aceitará mais modificações, eu quero mesmo é entender porque meu programa não imprimi o zero, uma vez que declarei `a = 0`.

Programa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>

main() {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    int a, b, auxiliar, i, n;

    a = 0;
    b = 1;

    printf("Digite um número: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\nSérie de Fibonacci:\n\n");
    printf("%d\n", b);

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        auxiliar = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = auxiliar;

        printf("%d\n", auxiliar);
    }
}
```

Desde já agradeço galera.

Comment: Porque o seu primeiro elemento da sequência é `b`, não `a`; veja `printf("%d\n", b)`

Comment: Cara, que erro ridículo... 
Agradeço aí brother. Vou criar uma resposta com a resolução. Abraços.

Comment: Mas você quer alterar o programa para que comece com fib(0) ? Para que fique 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5 ... ?

Comment: Não, @Isac, ele quereria fazer `printf("%d\n", a);` no lugar de `printf("%d\n", b);` porque ele é uma pessoa engraçada... [facepalm]

Answer (score 2):

Na verdade, faltaram algumas coisas:

- O `printf("%d\n", b);` deveria ser `if (n >= 1) printf("%d\n", b);`
- Antes da linha acima, teria que vir `if (n >= 0) printf("%d\n", a);`
- O `for` teria que ser `for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) { ... }`

O `{ ... }` acima significa:

```
{
    auxiliar = a + b;
    a = b;
    b = auxiliar;

    printf("%d\n", auxiliar);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
int i, n, a=0, b=1, pt=0;
printf("Informe um número, para ter sua sequência de Fibonacci\n");
scanf("%i", &n);
i=1;
do{
  if(i==1){
  b=0;
  }
  if(i==2){
  a=0;
  b=1;
   }
  if(i==3){
   a=0;
   b=1;
  }
  pt=a+b;
  a=b;
  b=pt;
  i++;
  printf("%d\n", pt);
  }
while(i<=n && pt<n);
do{
  if(i==1){
  b=0;
  }
  if(i==2){
  a=0;
  b=1;
   }
  if(i==3){
   a=0;
   b=1;
  }
if(n>=1 &&n<=6){
  pt=a+b;
  a=b;
  b=pt;
  i++;
  printf("%d\n", pt);
```

}
}

```
while(i>n && pt<n);

return 0;
```

}
cara tá ai o programa completo sem erros da para fazer algumas alterações para deixar ele mais enxuto mas funciona mesmo assim

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int n, fib = 0, aux = 0;    
    printf("Informe um numero para calcular a seq. de Fibonacci.\n ");

    scanf("%d", &n);
    while(fib <1000)//Só vai mostrar até 1000
    { 
        printf("%d-", fib);                   
        fib = fib + aux;                 
        aux = n;
        n = fib;        
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por favor, adicione mais detalhes para expandir sua resposta, como um código que funcione ou citações de documentação.